# What is the name for a phrase that is difficult to say repeatedly?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for a phrase that makes you stumble when repeated quickly?

Example: Say Big Blue Blanket 10 times.

Comment: Tongue-twister.

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Sorry, why not?  I think this was discussed in Meta, and there was nothing that convinced me this is inherently a bad thing.

Comment: @DJClayworth It's not an answer, it's a comment. If it were an answer, it would appear there. If you think it makes sense, *you* can answer the question that way, if you want to. Or you can answer the question with different information. Nobody should ever be forced to answer if they don't want to. And most comments are useful, even when they aren't actual answers.

Comment: One should not answer in comments because comments must be considered transient. An answer in comments that gets deleted is not helpful to the community. And it cannot be accepted by the OP.

Comment: @JasonBassford there's your proof, even the OP said HL supplied the  answer.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I never assume any comment will remain. There's nothing wrong with comments that disappear. Comments aren't meant to be helpful to the community. They're only supposed to be temporarily helpful to the person at which they are directed.

Comment: @JasonBassford sorry, my comment was directed to aparente001, not you.

Comment: @HotLicks Comments are not intended to be answers.

Answer (score 4):

Thesaurus.com gives zero results for synonyms of tongue-twister
https://www.thesaurus.com/noresult?term=tongue-twister&s=ts

That doesn't surprise me because I have never heard of another expression with that meaning.

So the answer is *Tongue-twister*.

---

Note that Reverse Dictionary gives a term for a single word that is difficult to pronounce, i.e. *Jawbreaker*

https://reversedictionary.org/wordsfor/Tongue-twister